# Incorrect click event when resize on libGdx

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to use scene2D, in libGDX, to detect click on object.

I have this simple Game sample :

```
Stage stage;

@Override
public void create()
{      
    this.stage = new Stage(1280, 720, true);
    MyActor actor = new MyActor();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    actor.setTexture(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("plateau.jpg"))));
    actor.setScale(0.1f);

    stage.addActor(actor);        

    actor.addListener(new InputListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {
            System.out.println("down"+Math.random());
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void render()
{
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

MyActor is a simple class extending Actor with a rendertexture.
The Event is working fine at start.
But when resizing the frame, while the Actor is streched as wanted, the coordinates of the click are not updated and thus misplaced.

How to make the stage using the new size of the items as base to the event ?

Thanks.